# my contact form isn't working properly; could be the logic

Tags: php

it keeps saying the fields are empty even when everything is correct. Heres my code:

```
    <p>*All Fields Required</p>

    <?php

    if(!empty($reply)){
echo "<p class='notify'>$reply</p>";
}
unset($reply);

    ?>

    <form method="post" action="index.php" id='contact'>

    <fieldset>

    <label>Name</label>
    <input type='text'  id="name" name="name" placeholder="type here" required value='<?php echo                     $name; ?>'>

    <label>Email</label>
    <input type='email' id="email" name="email" placeholder="type here" required value='<?php echo $email; ?>'>

    <label>Message</label>
    <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="type here" required><?php echo $message; ?>    </textarea>

    <p>Answer the following CAPTCHA question: </p>

    <label for="captcha">What color is Snow Whites hair?</label>

    <input type='text' name='captcha' id='captcha' size='5'required><br>

    <label for='action'>&nbsp;</label>

    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit"><br>

    </fieldset>  


    </form>
```

heres my index.php document:

```
<?php

    if($_POST['action']=='submit'){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $message=$_POST['message'];
    $captcha=strtolower($_POST['captcha']);
    }

     if(empty($name)||empty($email)||empty($message)){
    $reply='Sorry, one or more fields are empty. All fields are required.';
    include 'contactform.php';
    exit;
    }

    if(empty($captcha)|| $captcha != 'black'){
    $reply='The captcha answer is incorrect.';
    include 'contactform.php';
    exit;
    }

    $finalmessage="Name:$name\n";

    $finalmessage .="Email: $email\n";

    $finalmessage .="Message: \n$message";

//sending the message

    $to="rachel14yancey@gmail.com";

    $from="From: $email";

    $result= mail($to, $finalmessage, $from);

//Letting visitors know what happened

    if($result ==TRUE){
    $reply = "Thank you $name for contacting us.";
    unset($name);

    unset($email);

    unset($message);

     include 'contactform.php';
     exit;
}    else{
     $reply='Sorry $name. There was an error and the message could not be sent';

       unset($name);

       unset($email);

       unset($message);

       include 'contactform.php';

       exit;
       }
?>
```

Comment: It looks like you're looking for "action" in your POST array, but you're setting the name of your submit to "submit".  Try changing the name of the submit.

Comment: Check your form.  You don't have an element with `name="action"`.  So, `$_POST['action']` will never be set.  P.S. Why do you have `<label for='action'>` but nothing with `id="action"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the form submits:

```
*var_dump($_POST)

    **array (size=5)
      'name' => string 'John Doe' (length=6)
      'email' => string 'John.Doe@mail' (length=13)
      'message' => string 'Blah Blah Blah' (length=10)
      'captcha' => string 'White' (length=5)
      'submit' => string 'submit' (length=6)**
```

Instead of $_POST["action"] you can use $_POST["submit"] and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

You have no form field named `action`, therefore

```
if($_POST['action']=='submit'){
```

will ALWAYS evaluate to false, leaving all of the vars you're trying to create undefined.

You probably want `$_POST['submit']` instead, as that's the name of your actual `submit` button.

```
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit"><br>
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```